# Select button on webpage selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to automate a web page which has about 50 select buttons and here's an example

```
<input type="button" value="اختر" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Select$2')">
```

The part which is 'Select$2' is what changes from a button to another .. How can I specify the xpath of such a button?
I could select all the buttons using this

```
//input[@type='button']
```

But I would like to select specific button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use unique part of `onclick` attribute as locator try

```
//input[@type='button' and contains(@onclick, 'Select$2')]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot. How can I avoid selecting 20 and 21 and 22 and so on, as the xpath selects them too?

Comment: @YasserKhalil maybe try to add escape characters like `contains(@onclick, '\'Select$2\'')` to specify that you want `onclick` attribute to contain exactly string `'Select$2'`, but not sub-string `Select$2`... I'm not sure how it should be done in VBA. In Python we can just mix quotes `'//input[@type="button" and contains(@onclick, "'Select$2'")]'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could solve that point in VBA like that. Declare a variable `Dim sSel As String` then assign the value `sSel = "'Select$2'"` and finally used this line `bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='button' and contains(@onclick, " & sSel & ")]").Click`